# how to initialize seed value once in mersenne twister and use multiple times to get different random numbers each time

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-media-server

I am unable to get different random numbers from the MT,having seed with a fixed value(not changing as suggested by the testers). But when i call the same function twice in a program, it shows different values, but it don't randomize values even if i call the program multiple times.I don't understand where i am lagging  behind. 
Please suggest me on this

Below is the code pasted from mine .asc file(related to flash media server)

main.asc

```
  load(shuffle.asc);
  application.onAppStart=function()
  {
trace("Application Started");
  };

  application.onConnect=function(client,name)
   {

shuffledNumbers();
   }
```

shuffle.asc

```
var gen_random;


function  shuffledeck()
{
trace("shufledeck");

gen_random = new Array();

gen_random= new Array();

for(i=0;i<1000;i++)
{
gen_random[i]=genrand_int32();
}
trace("gen_random: "+gen_random); // HERE WE CAN SEE THE RANDOMLY GENERATED NUMBERS . THE PROBLEM: EVERYTIME I AM GETTING THE SAME RANDOM GENERATED VALUES.

}


    var N = 624;  
    var M  = 397;  
    var MATRIX_A  = 0x9908b0df;   /* constant vector a */  
    var UPPER_MASK  = 0x80000000; /* most significant w-r bits */  
    var LOWER_MASK  = 0x7fffffff; /* least significant r bits */  
    var mt =[]; /* the array for the state vector  */  
    var mti ;  
    var seed ;  
    var returnLength ;  
    var maxSize ;  
    var returnArray = new Array();




    /* initializes mt[N] with a seed */  
    function init_genrand($seed)
    {
        mt[0]= $seed & 0xffffffff;

        for (mti=1; mti<N; mti++) {
            mt[mti] = (1812433253 * (mt[mti-1] ^ (mt[mti-1] >> 30)) + mti);
            mt[mti] &= 0xffffffff;
            /* for >32 bit machines */


        }
    }

    /* initialize by an array with array-length */
    /* init_key is the array for initializing keys */
    /* key_length is its length */
    /* slight change for C++, 2004/2/26 */
    //    void init_by_array(unsigned long init_key[], int key_length)  

    /* generates a random number on [0,0xffffffff]-interval */  
    function genrand_int32()     
    {
        var y ;
        var mag01 =[0x0, MATRIX_A];
        /* mag01[x] = x * MATRIX_A  for x=0,1 */

        if (mti >= N)
        {
            /* generate N words at one time */
            var kk ;

            if (mti == N+1)   /* if init_genrand() has not been called, */
                init_genrand(15475454); /* a default initial seed is used */

            for (kk=0;kk<N-M;kk++) {
                y = (mt[kk]&UPPER_MASK)|(mt[kk+1]&LOWER_MASK);
                mt[kk] = mt[kk+M] ^ (y >> 1) ^ mag01[y & 0x1];
            }
            for (;kk<N-1;kk++) {
                y = (mt[kk]&UPPER_MASK)|(mt[kk+1]&LOWER_MASK);
                mt[kk] = mt[kk+(M-N)] ^ (y >> 1) ^ mag01[y & 0x1];
            }
            y = (mt[N-1]&UPPER_MASK)|(mt[0]&LOWER_MASK);
            mt[N-1] = mt[M-1] ^ (y >> 1) ^ mag01[y & 0x1];

            mti = 0;
        }

        y = mt[mti++];

        /* Tempering */
        y ^= (y >> 11);
        y ^= (y << 7) & 0x9d2c5680;
        y ^= (y << 15) & 0xefc60000;
        y ^= (y >> 18);
    //  trace("y: "+y);
        return y;
    }

    /* generates a random number on [0,0x7fffffff]-interval */  
    function genrand_int31()     
    {
        return (genrand_int32()>>1);
    }
```

Any help will be appriciated

PS: I have tried to convince them, by reseeding the int_genrand() function, and getting the output but, it compromises the predictability of randomness itseems.

Comment: Wath's wrong with builtin Math.random()?

Comment: @Smolniy Its deck of cards, which I need to shuffle. There we cant use, math.random(), so I am using  MT algorithm to get RNG values

Comment: You say "reseeding the int_genrand() would compromises the predictability of randomness". To me, whether you want predictable random numbers (the result you have right now) or not (what you seems to want)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are attempting to shuffle a deck of cards, I have found this function to be useful:

```
function fisherYates (myArray) {
  var i = myArray.length;
   while ( i-- ) {
     var j = Math.floor( Math.random() * ( i + 1 ) );
     var tempi = myArray[i];
     var tempj = myArray[j];
     myArray[i] = tempj;
     myArray[j] = tempi;
  }
}
```

usage:

```
myArray = [1,2,3,4,5];
fisherYates(myArray);
```

Comment: This is the same i am gonna use in later stage, but, at the place of `Math.random()` function , i need to use the function i have mentioned above i.e `shuffle()` function.

Comment: Hello @danjp, @Smolniy,

I think I have got the output, just by keeping the line `init_genrand(15475454);` outside the function(making it global)

Please let me know, is mine approach correct, 


Thank You

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem correctly. (in the question) In main.asc you call `shuffledNumbers()`, but there is no function with name `shuffledNumbers` in shuffle.asc. But usually when you use random generator with seed function, you need to call init seed function with current date as argument before use generator. Maybe in your case calling `init_genrand((new Date()).getTime());` will resolve the problem.